# how to read local text file with get command in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to open a text file with the get command in JavaScript so that I can populate a  tag in my html but I cant seem to make any progress with this one. The text file is located in the same folder as my html. I want to click the button that I have created and change the div tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Glorious Final </title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="six-point-star"></div>
<h1>JQuery Jedi </h1>

<div id="ornamentRow1"></div>

<p>
<h2>Ajax  Admiral</h2>
<div id="ornamentRow2"></div>
</p>
<h3>Javascript Janitor</h3>
<div id="custom"></div>

<h4>
    <button type="button" id="twinkle" >Twinkle Me Starmo</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="hangOrnament1()">Hang First Ornament</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="">Hang More Ornaments</button>

</h4>

<h5>

    <button type="button" onclick="">!!Open Me!!</button>

</h5>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Noe this is the javaScript function that I would like to use in a document called script.js i think that this is where I am going wrong

```
    function hangOrnament1()
    {
    //open "ornaments.txt" and change the innerHTML of the "ornamentRow1" div tag
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ornamentRow1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ornaments.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

I think that the problem is in the "GET" line at the bottom of this javascript function but I dont know what to do to fix it. I have read forms for a few hours trying to find a solution on my own but no luck.

Comment: Since you have `jquery` tagged, why aren't you using one of the simpler commands at your disposal, like http://api.jquery.com/load/?

Comment: Have you tried giving the physical address to the txt file? i.e. file:///C:/your/path/to/ornaments.txt

Comment: I just tried using this

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Starmo/ornaments.txt

Comment: Im still searching does anyone have a idea what to do here. I would really like to make this one work

Comment: i figured it out. the code is ok but the Internet Explorer will not process it because it is from a local machine and not a server. if it is ran on fire fix than it does ok and that is all that I really needed to do. thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JQuery code. (If you are using chrome, make sure it has --allow-file-access-from-files option enabled: (Assuming you have a paragraph/div tag with id="Para1")

```
var s="";
$.get('./ornaments.txt', function(data) {    
    var lines = data.split("\n");

    $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
                       s=s+"<br/>"+elem;
             });
});
$("#Para1").html(s);
```

`